# Why are applying log function?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import random
import math

low = int(input("Enter Lower number:- "))
up = int(input("Enter Upper number:- "))

# generating random number between the given numbers
x = random.randint(low, up)

print("\n\tYou've only ", round(math.log(up - low + 1, 2)),
      " chances to guess the integer!\n")

# Initializing the numberof times
count = 0

# for calculation of minimum guess
while count < math.log(up - low + 1, 2):
    count += 1

    # taking guessing number as input
    guess = int(input("Guess a number:- "))

    # testing
    if x == guess:
        print("Congratulations you did it in ", count, " try")

        # Once guessed, loop will break
        break

    elif x > guess:
        print("You guessed too small!")

    elif x < guess:
        print("You Guessed too high!")

# If Guessing is more than required guesses
if count >= math.log(up - low + 1, 2):
    print("\nThe number is %d" % x)
    print("\tBetter Luck Next time!")
```

can any one explain this line `math.log(up - low + 1, 2))` , why is this log function and comma 2

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind is that you can find the solution using binary search https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm
The 2 in the logarithm argument is the logarithm base.